# Two non circular curves enclosing constant angle sum

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-geometry

Two circles when passing through two fixed points on x-axis (red, purple) are shown enclosing $80^{\circ}, 100^{\circ}$ approximately at any two points on their chords.

How is it possible to find any of each of equations of any two continuously differentiable *non-circular curves* ( analytical or in differential form) passing through the given points such that the sum of varying subtended angles at C,D is always $180^{\circ}$?

[image]

Comment: Such curves cannot exist. If the angles at $C$ and $D$ can vary, then their sum cannot be always constant. But if the angles are constant, then their vertices lie on two circles.

Comment: Suppose D is held fixed at $70^\circ$, then the angle at C must be $110^\circ$ for every position it may take along its curve. Then its curve must be a circle. Likewise if C is held fixed, then for every position D occupies along its curve, the angle must be $70^\circ$ so its curve is also a circle.